# foreach inside a while loop in getting row value...?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop

Here's my code:

```
$inv = array('field1','field2','field3','field4');
$sql = "select * from table1 where id='1'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(!$result){
    print mysql_error();    
}else{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        foreach($inv as $i){
            print $row[$i];
        }
    }
}
```

table1 consist of the following field name: field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7

$inv = explode(',',$item) where $item = table2 $row[value] return a string with comma delimited which may consist 'field1,field2,field5' or 'field3,field4,field6'...etc.

How come it only print the value of field1? What's wrong with this code?

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        print $row['field1'];
        print $row['field2'];
        print $row['field3'];
        print $row['field4'];
    }
```

But if I do this way it will print all the value.

Comment: by the the fields name are dynamic that's why i need it to be like that.

Comment: `$inv` is already an array, why are you exploding it. print $i and see what the results are. I bet not what you think.

Comment: @user2138394 I can see from the revisions that you removed the `explode` line, which is (was?) the critical point others point out. Are you removing it because it isn't in your actually code?

Comment: thanks for the answer i just found my mistake, it's just a white space that i need to trim down. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You are using explode() on an array. Explode is used to create an array from a string. You do not have to do this, please refer to the manual http://php.net/explode to understand. Change the lines below

```
$inv = array('field1','field2','field3','field4');
$item = explode(',',$inv);
```

to

```
$item = array('field1','field2','field3','field4');
```

Comment: Right. Unless you `$item` = `'field1,field2,field3,field4'` there is no reason to explode. @user2138394

Comment: sorry i forgot to edit the question, $inv = another table $row['value'] that return a comma delimited string.

Comment: thanks for the answer i just found my mistake, it's just a white space that i need to trim down. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit I would guess that your field names contain leading spaces. You should check that with a `var_dump()` of the `$i` variables and you can solve it by trimming it:

```
$i = trim($i);
```